# A matrix client (nheko) demands another matrix client for its build

Tags: build, build-dependencies

I'm trying to build the latest nheko release (0.8.1) on Devuan Beowulf (with a self-built Boost 1.73.0).

I get stuck during CMake configuration, when it says:

```
  By not providing "FindMatrixClient.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "MatrixClient", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "MatrixClient"
  (requested version 0.4.1) with any of the following names:
```

I thought nheko *is* a Matrix client. What exactly does nheko want from me here?

Answer (score 0):

MatrixClient refers to this repository: https://github.com/Nheko-Reborn/mtxclient

It's the library Nheko uses to communicate with Matrix servers.

You can use the bundled version using `-DUSE_BUNDLED_MTXCLIENT=ON`, which will not require the lib to be installed separately.